# Junit - cannot read from std in

Tags: java, junit

When I try to run my unit tests and e.g. add `System.in.read()` and I run them via Intellij, the console to which I normally can type does not accept any input... As if Junit was redirecting stdin somehow... I basically want the test to wait for my key press - is there an alternative way to do this or reset stdin?

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are meant to be automated.  That means no user intervention so you shouldn't require a user to type something into the console for a test.

If you need to test your code that reads console input from `System.in` then your test should temporarily replace `System.in` with something else.

```
System.setIn( myInputStream);
```

Just make sure you set it back when you are done.  It's probably best to do this in a `@Before` and put it back in an `@After` like this:

```
private InputStream oldIn = null;


@Before
public void replaceStdIn(){
    //save reference to console STDIN so we can put it back later
    oldIn = System.in;
}


@After
public void restoreStdIn(){
   System.setIn(oldIn);
}


@Test
public void testConsoleInput(){

   InputStream mockStdIn = ...

   System.setIn(mockStdIn);

   //now do your test as usual

}
```

I've use Junit's `Rule` to make my own `Rule` that does this for me automatically for all System streams when I need to.